# Authenticate Custom Content Block via SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication, marketingcloudapi

I have Custom Content Block which is a Node.js App hosted on Heroku Cloud.
I want my Custom App to be available for usage only to the users of my SFMC Platform.

I have looked for the Marketing Cloud API's but was not able to find anything relevant related to Custom App authentication/Authorization.

Comment: Have a look at the Custom Content Block SDK module on trailhead, it talks to the `triggerAuth()` function which sounds like it could solve your problem. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/content-builder-block-sdk/build-a-custom-block

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, I think we now need to use the triggerAuth2() SDK method, now that we can no longer create legacy packages and need to use the newer OAuth Authorization Flow. It's a similar mechanism to the original triggerAuth() method, by the look of things... Creates a 1px hidden iframe and after going via the authorize endpoint, redirects to your app's login page with the access code appended as a query string param.